# Value not outputting in node.js api

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, api, cloudinary

i have an array of base64 images, i want to upload them to cloudinary, so i was looping through the array and doing the upload, but when i try to access the result it give me an empty array

```js
let img = ['base64u/dfu...', 'base64u/dfu...','base64u/dfu...']

const func =  () => {
      let arr = [];

      img.map(async (item, i) => {
        const fileStr = item;

        const uploadResponse = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(fileStr, {
          upload_preset: "services",
        });

        arr.push(uploadResponse.url);
        console.log(arr) 
       //['http://res.cloudinary.com/mozy/image/upl..','http://res.cloudinar...']

        
      });

      return arr;
 };
 
     console.log(func()) //[]
```

how do i get the value

Comment: Your code snippet can't run successfully. Could you provide another one?

Comment: @gricn i have updated it

Comment: I have use Node.js run this code locally. Anything works fine. I don't know what "cloudinary" is, but I use "console.log(arr)" just before "return arr;" and it shows the correct answer. And the last console.log function also works fine.

Comment: I think the await function(await cloudinary.uploader.upload) is the key of the solution. I will try to use other async/await function to test later.